# Keep the same URL for Outlook 2007 Publish Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

Outlook has a feature that will [publish your calendar](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/howdoi/?p=128) to the web at certain intervals (usually every 20 minutes or so). I have this enabled, and have invited colleagues to subscribe to my calendar through various ways (mostly via "Add Calendar by URL" in Google Calendar). It publishes to a URL in the form webcal://calendars.office.microsoft.com/pubcalstorage/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.ics. I am about to reinstall Windows, and once I reinstall Outlook I want to have the same URL for my published calendar (so that my colleagues' subscriptions do not break). Is there a way to get the same URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just decided to test it myself. It appears that if you right-click and "Remove from Server" on the old computer before upgrading, and have the exact same calendar name in Outlook, it will generate the same URL when you re-share it on the new computer.